# PSComputerName empty when using Format-Table

Tags: powershell

If I use simple command:

```
$pcname = "Server2"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service | Where Name -CLike "Servi*"
}
```

I get service `Name`, `Description`, `Status`, `PSComputerName`.

If I try to format columns:

```
$pcname = "Server2"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service | Where Name -CLike "Servi*" |
        Format-Table -Property Status,Name,DisplayName,PSComputerName -AutoSize
}
```

`PSComputerName` is coming as an empty value.

If I try to add custom property, I cant reference variable value, column is still empty:

```
$pcname = "Server2"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service |
        Where Name -clike "Servi*" |
        Format-Table -Property Status, Name, DisplayName,
            @{Name='MachineName';Expression={$pcname}} -AutoSize
}
```

How do I get `PSComputerName` when using formatting or how do I reference variable `$pcname` inside the expression?

Comment: The property `PSComputerName` is added by `Invoke-Command` when the remote data is returned to the caller. Your 3rd code snippet doesn't work b/c `$pcname` inside the scriptblock is a different variable than `$pcname` outside the scriptblock. Change `@{Name='MachineName';Expression={$pcname}}` to `@{Name='MachineName';Expression={$using:pcname}}` or (better) `@{Name='MachineName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}` to make it work. Alternatively put `Format-Table` after the `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put in a variable the first output and then format the table:

```
$service = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock { Get-Service | Where Name -CLike "Servi*" }
$service | Format-Table -Property Status,Name,DiaplyName,PSComputerName -AutoSize
```